# PhpStorm dirs are not showing on tree

Tags: phpstorm

I will re-upload my project on my local. But I cannot see my dirs on tree like:

[image]

But the other projects allow seen dirs:

[image]

I checked my views, tools any settings and return to default settings. But its not showing ?

Comment: Something wrong with your project. based on screenshot the files have light yellow background + the path on the Navigation Bar comes from the disk root folder ... This means that these files are outside of the project .. so something is broken.

Comment: 1) Just close IDE; 2) go to the PROJECT_ROOT folder and delete `.idea` subfolder (this project settings); 3) Launch IDE again and using "Open" point to the project root folder to create new project from existing files.

Comment: Have you use "Open Project" method?
Are all of your files in the same parent directory?

Answer (score 0):

From the first screenshot it looks like the whole D: drive was used as a project root.

In PhpStorm do File > Close Project, then go to D: and delete .idea folder, then go to PhpStorm, press Open and select D:\UserData\Home\b****lu-app directory, then press OK.